# How to redirect unathorized user in web.php to login page?

Tags: laravel, authentication, roles

I'm creating custom admin panel in Laravel and trying to make redirect to login page for unathorized users. There is so many posts about it in the web, but they are for older versions of Laravel and I couldnt find anything for 10. Here is web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['role:admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function()
{
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('admin');

    Route::resource('games', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PostController::class);

});
```

What should I add here to redirect users to login page?

Comment: unauthorized? as in they don't have the correct role? ... what is this `role` middleware you are using now?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use [Spatie\laravel-permissions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v6/basic-usage/basic-usage) based on role:admin middleware.

You have to make your own middleware, for example "IsAdmin"

```
php artisan make:middleware IsAdmin
```

and then code authorization logic in the handle() function of your new middleware.

The hasRole() method is from laravel-permissions package, if you have other system for permissions then edit this logic.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ( $request->user()->hasRole('admin']) ) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Add your new middleware to your route. Also you should add Laravel auth middleware to check if user is authenticated.

```php
use \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin;

Route::middleware(['auth', IsAdmin::class])->prefix('admin')->group(function()
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect unauthorized users to the login page in Laravel 10, you can use the built-in auth middleware along with any custom middleware for role checking.

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PostController;

Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('admin');
    Route::resource('games', PostController::class);
});
```

Create a custom middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware EnsureUserHasRole
```

EnsureUserHasRole.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EnsureUserHasRole
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (!Auth::check() || !$request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            return redirect(route('login'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register the middleware in Http/Kernel.php.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureUserHasRole::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new guard for admin in auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

  'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
],
```

and check guards in web.php

```
    Route::middleware('auth:admin')
```

for redirect user
in Middleware Authenticate.php

```
enter code hereprotected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
{
    if (Route::is('admin.*')) {
        return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('admin.login');
    }
    return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('login');
}
```